# AJAX json_encode de ficheiro PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Bom dia. Estou a tentar construir um formulário em que o input é validado por um ficheiro PHP através de uma chamada via AJAX, mas estou a ter problemas na forma como recebo o "data" no callback.

Esta é a minha chamada via AJAX:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var msg_subject = $("#msg_subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {name:name, email:email, msg_subject:msg_subject},
        success : function(data){
            if (data.code == "200"){
                alert("Success: " +data.msg);
            } else {
              alert( data);
            }
        }
    });

  });
```

E este o ficheiro PHP onde é efectuada a validação:

```
<?php

$errors = array();


/* NAME */
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errors["name"] = "The name is required";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

/* EMAIL */
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errors["email"]= "The email is required";
} else if(!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors["email"] = "The email contains invalid characters";
}else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

/* MSG SUBJECT */
if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
    $errors["subject"]= "Subject is required";
} else {
    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
}


if(empty($errorMSG)){
    $msg = "Name: ".$name.", Email: ".$email.", Subject: ".$msg_subject.", Message:".$message;
    echo json_encode(['code'=>200, 'msg'=>$msg]);
    exit;
}

    echo json_encode(['code'=>400, $errors);

?>
```

O objectivo era usar o método "json_encode" do php para devolver a resposta em formato de objecto pois preciso de acessar as posições para formatar os campos do formulario que tiverem erro, algo como este exemplo:

```
$obj = {
    "name":"Jose", 
    "email":"something@hotmail.com",
    "assunto":"bla bla bla"
    }
```

Contudo, apesar de estar a usar o json_encode, a resposta vai sempre em formato "string". Não consigo perceber o que estou a fazer mal. Agradeço toda a ajuda

**EDIT**
Alterei o código no AJAX para o seguinte:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {name:name, email:email, msg_subject:msg_subject},
        success : function(data){
            if (data.code == "200"){
                console_log(data.msg.name)
                alert("Success: " +data.msg.name);
            } else {
              console_log(data.err.name)
            }
        }
    });
```

mas não tenho qualquer output na consola nem qualquer erro. Estou a dar em louco

**EDIT**
Resultado do output com formulario vazio:

```
ajax.php:99 
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (a)
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (a)
readyState: 4
responseText: "<br />↵<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp64\www\Test\process_test.php on line <i>31</i></th></tr>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>↵<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>↵<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0002</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>404648</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Test\process_test.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\process_test.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>↵</table></font>↵<br />↵<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\wamp64\www\Test\process_test.php on line <i>31</i></th></tr>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>↵<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>↵<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0002</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>404648</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Test\process_test.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\process_test.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>↵</table></font>↵<br />↵<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: msg_subject in C:\wamp64\www\Test\process_test.php on line <i>31</i></th></tr>↵<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>↵<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>↵<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0002</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>404648</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\Test\process_test.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\process_test.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>↵</table></font>↵{"code":200,"msg":{"name":null,"email":null,"subject":null}}"
setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (a)
statusText: "OK"
success: ƒ ()
then: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Mas JSON é uma string mesmo. O AJAX do jQuery já identifica a resposta da requisição e "parsea" automaticamente. A final, qual o problema do seu código?

Comment: Boas LipESprY. Como é que eu faço para aceder por exemplo ao valor do "nome"? Se se tratasse de um objecto poderia fazer por exemplo obj.name. Essa é a minha dúvida.

Comment: Ahh sim. Agora entendi. Acontece que na variável `$msg` você concatenou os valores. Você deveria fazer uma `array` associativa e o JavaScript iria receber como objeto, como já faz com o restante da resposta. Aliás, o colega @WeesSmith já formulou uma resposta resolvendo isso! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Organizei para que você possa trabalhar com todos os dados que serão retornados pelo `PHP`, transformando a variável `$msg` em um `array()` com o conteúdo:

```
if(empty($errorMSG)){
    $msg = array("name"=>$name,"email"=>$email,"subject"=>$msg_subject,"message"=>$message);
    echo json_encode(['code'=>200, 'msg'=>$msg]);
}else{
    echo json_encode(['code'=>400, $errors]);
}
```

No callback do `$.ajax()` o parâmentro `data` vai ser esse `json_encode()` do `PHP`:

```
success : function(data){
    if (data.code == 200){
        alert("Success: " +data.msg.name);
        //ou uma forma de ver todo conteúdo do retorno é
        console.log(data);
        //ou apenas o conteúdo do elemento msg
        console.log(data.msg);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
},
error:function(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Lembrando que o `alert()` não vai mostrar um objeto retornado, apenas vai aparecer [obj Obj].

Comment: Olá Wees. Antes de mais obrigado pela ajuda. Então como é que eu faço para no callback do AJAX conseguir aceder aos valores desse objecto? por exemplo se eu quiser imprimir o valor  de array['name']?

Comment: @SergioNeves ele já colocou isso na resposta: `data.msg.name`. Leia o código com mais atenção. Oo

Comment: assim como coloquei ali dentro do `alert()` vc vai acessar o parâmetro `data`, que vai conter todo retorno, a partir dai vc usa as chaves do `PHP`, por exemplo: `data.code` ou `data.msg.name`

Comment: Pois o problema é exactamente esse. É que eu já tinha tentado essa solução, mas continuo sem ter qualquer tipo de Output no lado do formulário, esteja bem preenchido ou com erros. Nem sequer me faz o log para a consola

Comment: editei a resposta e adicionei o `error` no `$.ajax`, verifica no console qual o problema que esta ocorrendo

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta com o resultado do output ao enviar o formulário completamente vazio. Dá para perceber que ao enviar o formulário vazio ele responde com  {"code":200,"msg":{"name":null,"email":null,"subject":null}} o que não faz sentido. No ficheiro PHP o meu array de erros devia estar preenchi se eu submeter o formulario sem dados

Comment: Mesmo preenchendo o formulário correctamente, o AJAX não mostra o Alert

Comment: olha ai o erro `Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp64\www\Test\process_test.php on line 31`